# MovieClipSWFLoader.play() and stop() cannot work

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, air, flex4

I have a problem in playing and stoping the loaded swf file with "MovieClipSWFLoader”.
MovieClipSWFLoader.load() seems to work correctly, but play() and stop() does not work.

I use ...

- Action Script 3.0
- Flex SDK 4.6.0
- Adobe AIR 13.0.0.83

My source codes are as follow:

https://gist.github.com/mitsuse/693aefa9ae9f83f66704

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I tried “Embed” instead of using the path of a swf file directly.  

https://gist.github.com/mitsuse/693aefa9ae9f83f66704/484cb339ce35369c6f64e8e46e2b17792479a4ff

“MovieClipSWFLoader.content” returns the instance of “MovieClip”,  but “MovieClipSWFLoader.content.play()” and “MovieClipSWFLoader.content.stop” seem not to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting the `movieClip` property of the `MovieClipSWFLoader`. This way you will know if the actual content is a MovieClip which can be played.

And if so, try manipulating the MovieClip directly, just to be sure you what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for fast response :-)  
I tried call “movieClip” directly, but it returns null.  
https://gist.github.com/mitsuse/693aefa9ae9f83f66704/25f995209c2c5bbcc87dad10cd57aa44196c9b4f


I understand that “MovieClipSWFLoader.movieClip” converts the type of “MovieClipSWFLoader.content” by reading “movieClip”.

However, in my code, the type of “content” is “AVM1Movie”.


https://gist.github.com/mitsuse/693aefa9ae9f83f66704/baec6733d275a29ba9e98ae59ed3ea116d15f53b


How can I pause and resume the movie with this instance?

Comment: Oh this tells it all! It's because you are loading .swf file which is created in either AS1 or AS2. Unfortunately, there are a lot of limitations, and that's why you are having a problem. Check this reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/AVM1Movie.html

Comment: My problem seems to be solved thanks to you!
I close this question.